Movie about old people who want to win a young body in a game
A bunch of old millionaires go to a BIOTECH company to buy a young body.
At the beginning, an old guy talks to the company owner and he asks for 5 billion dollars to participate in the process of getting a new young body. Then they say will have to play a game with other 9 millionaires and after the game is over only the winner will have the young body.
The game: 10 young people (5 women and 5 men) appear in an abandoned building; the game master shows holograms of old people with bio-briefing (6 man and 4 women). You can't tell which young person corresponds to each old person, even gender can be misleading because someone had a sex change.

They have to kill one person every hour or the game will kill one of them at random;
After kill someone, the killer has to select the correct hologram of his/her victim or willalso be killed if they make the wrong choice.

I watched it last weekend, not sure if it was on the FOX channel.

How do millionaires afford 5 billion?

So you want me to change it to multi-millionaires?

I just mean, the basic meaning of a millionaire is that they have millions. While a millionaire could have billions, that's like saying Einstein was smarter than a dog. It just reminds me of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1z-AxgueBRk and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8M5-7RbOV9s

Sorry maybe my litle english knowledge miss your point. But if you say a millionaire could have billions why you ask How do millionaires afford 5 billion?. I guess you try some kind of sarcasm, but I totally missed.

Tongue in cheek, slight sarcasm. I'm not picking on you.

Real Playing Game from 2013.

The wealthy Steve Battier (Rutger Hauer) is desperate to find a way to stay alive, as he is both elderly and terminally ill. When a company known as RPG offers him the chance to become young again in return for a large amount of money, he jumps at the chance to participate. Ten millionaires from throughout the world will be placed inside younger bodies for ten hours, but with the catch that every hour someone will die.

Here's the trailer:




Yes, that is. Just wonder how you find it. I search for Game on IMDB and only found Game of thrones and Hunger games, but this didnt appear.

Well, I knew the movie. ;) And, well, searching for a title with 'game' on IMDb will yield hundreds of results.

@Walt - Is it any good? The premise sounds interesting.

Not great but was funny (dark funny not sitcom funny). And keep me interested enought to see how will end. But I wouldnt watch again. So watch under you own risk.

@SystemDown Knew of the movie (and that Hauer's in it). Never watched it, but did remember the premise because it's unique (but TBH doesn't make a lot of sense). BTW, Juan, if you don't want to watch it again, why are you looking for it? ;)

@Walt. I Like the puzzle. So I think would like to create one for the puzzle stackoverflow and see how people invent the best strategy for it.
